# generate mapping and documents in Symfony 2 for mongodb?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-mongodb

Im using DoctrineMongoDBBundle and I was wondering if it's possible to generate mapping information and documents from an existing mongodb database.

Just like the following set of commands would do with the ORM:

```
doctrine:mapping:convert; doctrine:mapping:import; doctrine:generate:entities;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research it doesn't seem like this type of reverse engineering is possible. DoctrineMongoDBBundle is still in BETA version and they might very well incorporate it in their stable release.

In the meantime I turned to [Shanty](https://github.com/coen-hyde/Shanty-Mongo) (used with Zend Framework) who lets me declare models  without having to declare all the parameters and allows me to retrieve entire collections of my db.